# why the if condition doesn't check the nulls

Tags: c#, .net, string

I was trying to check the null in my var but it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 private void GenerateImage()
    {
        //Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata.Helper test = new Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata.Helper();
         var selectedstory = Webster.Client.Modules.Metadata.Helper.SelectedStoryItem;

        if((selectedstory.Slug).Trim()!=null)
        {
         //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedstory.Slug))
       //{

           if (File.Exists(pathToImage))
           {
              }
           else
           {
               this.dialog.ShowError("Image file does not exist at the specified location", null);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           this.dialog.ShowError("Slug is Empty,please enter the Slug name", null);
       }
    }
```

I know selectedstory.Slug has the null value, which is why I used an **if** condition to check, but it's throwing right there in the if condition.

Can some one please advise what is the right way to check.

Comment: C# should have a [safe-navigation operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator) There was a proposal on C# but it's [not yet implemented](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/192177/a-bit-more-c-syntactic-sugar-for-nulls)  Some enterprising users [made one](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/01/nullpropagating_extension_meth.html) for themselves while they cannot wait

Comment: Thanks Michael for your helpful links. I was not much aware of extension methods usage but got good understanding now :) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call methods on a null reference. Take out the `.Trim()`.

Comment: Would you recommend OOP adds a null check to selectedStory.Slug, or enclose his code in a try/catch?

Comment: OP already has a null check, just with an unneeded .trim() which is also causing the problem.  If the Trim() call is removed, the code will work as intended.

Comment: If `selectedstory` is null then a null check on `selectedstory.Slug` will throw a null reference exception because you're trying to reference a property of a null reference.

Comment: @PaulSasik, true, but `selectedstory` isn't null, `selectedstory.Slug` is. OP already said that in the question. It's not the `.Slug` that's the problem, it's the `.Trim()`.

Answer (score 6):

```
if((selectedstory.Slug).Trim()!=null)
```

will first call the `Trim()` method on the string and THEN check for null.  This is the part that is failing: you are trying to call an instance method on a null object.

what you want is like this:

```
if ( selectedstory != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedstory.Slug) )
```

Comment: Thanks everyone,to enlighten me with so many options,@Muad'Dib code works for me.tested and looks good in my end. Thanks again

Comment: ,sorry i couldn't use this part of your code it says always null bcoz some of my var are null in that object "selectedstory != null"

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedstory.Slug))
```

That removes the need to call Trim on the property you're checking.

Comment: +1 for using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` that remove the need for the `Trim` method call

Comment: it should be noted that IsNullOrWhiteSpace is only available in .net 4 and up

Comment: @Leo thanks for elucidating that-- I added that note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i finally come up with

```
    try
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedstory.Slug))
            {

                if (File.Exists(pathToImage))
                {
                    string SlugName = selectedstory.Slug;
                    if (pathToImage.Contains(SlugName))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.dialog.ShowError("Image file name is not same as Slug name", null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.dialog.ShowError("Image file does not exist at the specified location", null);
                }

            }
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.dialog.ShowError("Slug is Empty,please enter the Slug name", null);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Rohit am not sure how to give the credit,bcoz i used experts comment from Joe White,Kevin and dbaseman ideas and code